# How to write recursion for string sequence of bits

Tags: python

I am trying to write a script that will take as input a dictionary where the keys are bits and the values are probabilities to represent a given bit string. For example, what are all the different ways I can represent '10011001' using the dictionaries p1 = {'00':1/2, '01':1/4, '10':1/4}
p2 = {'0':1/3, '01':1/3, '10':1/3}
p3 = {'00':1/8, '01':1/4, '0':3/8,'1010':2/8}

My attempt so far:

```
def start_fun(seq,dx):
'''takes as input a sequence and outputs possible starting strings'''

paths = [] 

for key in dx:
    if seq[: len(key)] == key:
        paths.append([dx[key],seq[len(key):]])

for i in range(len(paths)):
    paths[i] = recursion(paths[i][-1],paths[i][0],dx)

return paths
```

```
def recursion(seq,prob,dic):
    if seq == '':
        return 1
    
    elif len(seq) == 2 and seq not in dic or len(seq) == 1 and seq not in dic:
        return 0
            
    else:
        for key in dic:
            if seq[:len(key)] == key:
                prob = dic[key] * prob
                seq = seq[len(key):]
        
        return prob * recursion(seq,prob,dic)
        
print(start_fun(sequence,dic))
```

This just gives me the string and the probability after one step. I don't know how to continue for all the possible remaining paths, especially because the bits can be length one or two.

Comment: Welcome to SO and congrats on your first question. Please post your full code.  What is `count`?

Comment: Also if you want to use recursion to do this you'll have to define a function and call into that function recursively.  It isn't strictly necessary to use recursion to solve this problem, but it would be one way to do it.

Comment: def start_fun(seq,dx):
    '''takes as input a sequence and outputs possible starting strings'''
    
    paths = [] 
    
    for key in dx:
        if seq[: len(key)] == key:
            paths.append([dx[key],seq[len(key):]])
       
    return paths


def recursion(seq,dic):
    if seq == '':
        return 1
    
    else:
        return 0

Comment: I don't understand how to keep a running total and how to check every path. I can't tie everything together.

Comment: Can anybody help?

Comment: Could you give more details?  When you call `start_fun` it's not exactly clear what are the `sequence` and `dic` arguments you're passing it.